# Android next/previous layout style

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, material-design

I've been looking online for a possible solution and was not able to achieve this so I would like to know how you can recreate or use (if it exists) the bottom previous and next arrows [app i'm working on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLZfh.png).

I have been able to re-create it but the next and the next(image arrow) are not united therefore when I click on next or the arrow it will act as if i only clicked on one of the two. Any help on how to possibly do this?

Cheers.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:background="#F0F0F0"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_previous"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:text="NEXT"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_next_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: why dont you use a viewpager instead and show the indicators with https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator

Answer (score 0):

You could use drawableLeft for the textview. save this as `footer.xml` and use this at the in every layout you want like below.

```
<include layout="@layout/footer" />
```

footer.xml

```
<LinearLayout
        android:background="#F0F0F0"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_previous"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:text="NEXT"
            android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_next_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```